# How to read slope from HYDRO1k database for Asia

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

The Hydro1k database for Asia is provided by USGS. It is available [here](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) as GTOPO30 HYDRO 1K.

I tried to read the slope values for the Kumamoto area in Japan but the results all came out as 55537(same as for the sea). The slope is shown different when I open it in QGIS.

Here is the prj file:

```
PROJCS["US National Atlas Equal Area",GEOGCS["Unspecified datum based upon the Clarke 1866 Authalic Sphere",DATUM["D_Sphere_Clarke_1866_Authalic",SPHEROID["Clarke_1866_Authalic_Sphere",6370997,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",45],PARAMETER["central_meridian",100],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
import osgeo
from osgeo import gdal,osr
import ogr
geo = gdal.Open('/home/Downloads/gt30h1kas/as_slope.bil') #slope file

# Read the projection from prj file
ds = gdal.Open('/home/Downloads/gt30h1kas/as_dem.prj')
prj=ds.GetProjection()
geo_ref=osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)

# Reference system for input coordinates
point_ref=ogr.osr.SpatialReference()
point_ref.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

ctran2=ogr.osr.CoordinateTransformation(point_ref, geo_ref)

arr = geo.ReadAsArray()

geotransform = geo.GetGeoTransform() 
originX = geotransform[0]
originY = geotransform[3]
pixelWidth = geotransform[1]
pixelHeight = geotransform[5]

# Kumamoto (32.8031° N, 130.7079° E)
[lon,lat,z]=ctran2.TransformPoint(130.7079, 32.8031) 
print(lon,lat)
offx = int( (lon-originX)/pixelWidth )
offy = int( (lat-originY)/pixelHeight )
print(offx, offy, arr[offx][offy])
```

Here is the output:

```
2810038.798891878 -837540.6774932265
7165 7281 55537
```

Please help me find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The [Hydro1k documentation](https://www.usgs.gov/media/files/hydro-1k-readme) says that the projection is in Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area and the origin of the projection is different for each hydro1k continent file.

[image: hydro1k]

Following [this post](https://losetposet.wordpress.com/tag/data/), I used the base LAEA WKT [linked](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/28/esriwkt/) and modified the origin coordinates to match the hydro1k documentation for Asia. I was able to get what appears to be the correct projection with the stream.e00 file for asia.

```
PROJCS["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area",GEOGCS["Unknown",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["Unknown",6371007.181,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",45],PARAMETER["central_meridian",100],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```